# How to center sticky header without it jumping during scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to center "topofpage" in the page. I added to the CSS "text-align: center", but it jumps/jerks when it first starts scrolling moving it slightly to the right. Without the added CSS it appears left, and doesn't jump or jerk when scrolling. How can topofpage be centered without the jump/jerking when scrolling?

```
<div class="topofpage" id="mytopofpage">
  <h2>My topofpage</h2>
</div>

/* Style the topofpage */
.topofpage {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Page content */
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the topofpage with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the topofpage gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the topofpage
var topofpage = document.getElementById("mytopofpage");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = topofpage.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the topofpage when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    topofpage.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    topofpage.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Comment: share the code what you tried

Comment: If you're concerned about copyrights, just change the names and proprietary info. You cannot copyright basic CSS and JS concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the `text-align: center;` to `.header` or `.topofpage` class not to the `sticky` class and change the padding of `header` class to `padding: 10px 0px;`

```
.topofpage {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
  <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That has the same problem. When you scroll, the My Header jerks to the right.

Comment: I have updated the solution. change the padding of `header' class to `padding: 10px 0px;`

Answer (score 0):

This is todo with the `box-sizing` css property. By default it is set to `content-box` which causes sizing issues as the border/padding is added on top of the width.

You can fix it adding this css:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing